# How to integrate keyboard events while reading for input - golang [Need cross platform support]

Tags: go, command-line-interface, tui

I am implementing a CLI application using golang.[Need cross platform compatibility]

My requirement is that when a user is being prompted for an input and after the user has finished typing if the user presses Ctrl+D without pressing Enter then some data processing should take place and user must get their response.

I tired looking for libraries like 'term-box' and 'tcell' for keyboard events but they are good at detecting keyboard keys and there is no option for getting any kind of user input.

I would like to have a standard input prompt along with keyboard events in golang for my CLI application.

Below is some reference code:

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

fmt.Println("#Please press CTRL+D to process data")
for {

    fmt.Print("\n your-input>")
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if strings.HasSuffix(text, "\\\n") {
        text1, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        text += text1
    }

    //would like to have some kind of keyboard event here which will handle (Ctrl+D)
    // if(key == Ctrl+D){
             //then do some data processing
       } else {
            //let the user keep typing their text
       }


    text = strings.TrimSpace(strings.Replace(text, "\n", "", -1))

    fmt.Print("\n response> " + getProcessedData(text))

}
```